# Store and retrieve user favorites in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have an android app that pulls information from **mysql db** and displays it in a list. Each list item has a **favorite** button that upon click updates the db with the username and with the list item.

I can get all user favorites using relational and foreign key.
What I am trying to achieve is when the user re-logs in to the App and scrolls for available items he can already see which items he marked as favorite without going to his favorites page.

So for example when you are scrolling in your facebook page you can already see which posts you liked.

How can I achieve that?

First table

```
|------------------|--------------|----|-------|
|      Column      |     Type     |Null|Default
|------------------|--------------|----|-------|
|    //**id**//    |   int(11)    | No |
|    car_vendor    |  varchar(20) | No |
|    car_model     |  varchar(20) | No |
|    car_petro     |  varchar(10) | No |
| car_transmition  |  varchar(10) | No |
|     car_hand     |   int(11)    | No |
|  car_spedometer  |  varchar(7)  | No | 
|  car_engine_vol  |  varchar(4)  | No |
|   car_category   |   int(11)    | No |
|  car_post_date   |     date     | No |
```

second table

```
|----------------|------------|----|
|     Column     |    Type    |Null| Default
|----------------|------------|----|
|   //**id**//   |   int(11)  | No |
|    username    | varchar(20)| No |
|  favorites_id  |   int(11)  | No | <<< foreign key points to ID on first table
```

Comment: If you can post the metadata for your tables, it will make it easier for someone to reply.

Comment: there are two tables total 

cars
|------
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**id**//|int(11)|No|
|car_vendor|varchar(20)|No|
|car_model|varchar(20)|No|
|car_petro|varchar(10)|No|
|car_transmition|varchar(10)|No|
|car_hand|int(11)|No|
|car_spedometer|varchar(7)|No|
|car_engine_vol|varchar(4)|No|
|car_category|int(11)|No|
|car_post_date|date|No|

Fvorites
|------
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**id**//|int(11)|No|
|username|varchar(20)|No|
|favorites_id|int(11)|No| <<< foregin key to id collomn at cars table.

Comment: Just edit your question if you want to add code

Comment: I don't get are you really want. How do you want to show the favorites? You can put a check box inside each item of the list...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ask the db for that information,

the moment you get the list of all products you can do a LEFT JOIN, that can be used to connect a product, if liked, to the user. You can do something like this.

```
SELECT CAR_VENDOR,
    A.CAR_MODEL,
    A.CAR_PETRO,
    A.CAR_TRANSMITION,
    A.CAR_HAND,
    A.CAR_SPEDOMETER,
    A.CAR_ENGINE_VOL,
    A.CAR_CATEGORY,
    A.CAR_POST_DATE,
    B.USERNAME
FROM TABLE_ONE AS A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_TWO AS B ON B.FAVORITES_ID = A.ID
AND B.USERNAME = "actual user username"
```

This query should do the work, I didn't test it but you can take as an idea where to start

Only the object with the preference should have the username field filled

**EDIT** ------------------------------------------------

Taking the case that the OP presented we have that:

- We have a single table that is a list of objects (cars) with their specific parameters (engine size, hand, model, category etc)
- We have a N to N table that can connect each product to one or more user and each user to one or more product
- We probably have a table of people (the "username" column of table two, that I wish to call "LIKES" should be a foreign key connected to the primary key in PEOPLE table)

The behavior is simple, we want something social-like where a person can "upvote" a car, obviously *we don't want multiple votes on the same car from the same person* thus we have to disable the function in case he/she has already voted.

We take in example a normal page in which a person has already voted some products and want to see the complete list.

In this case we want to see:

- The *COMPLETE* list of item, no matter what.
- The items that have already got a vote from *that particular user*.

One way to handle this is connecting CARS table with LIKES table (I leave the anagraphic of user outside to simplify).

The way to do this is using a **JOIN** connecting the two tables on the id of the car.

This SQL command will return a set of line that are the combination of each line inside the CARS followed by the relative username.

This will lead to mutiple lines for the same CAR, one for each upvoting user, needing a business logic to handle the problem of showing the correct page.

A step further in SQL logic is to use a LEFT JOIN.

The **LEFT JOIN** will include **ALL** the record from the first table and will connect them with the matching line of the second one.

Thus joining CARS with LIKE on car-id AND asking for the username that we want, will return the complete list of cars (all record from left) connected to (and only to) the records that match the username related condition.

The example can be this:

```
|         CARS         |
|  ID  |     MODEL     |
|------+---------------|
|   1  +     FORD      |
|   2  +     OPEL      |
|   3  +    FERRARI    |
|   4  +      GM       |
|----------------------|

|        LIKES         |
|  USERNAME  |  CAR_ID |
|------------+---------|
|   KEVIN    |    3    |
|    PAUL    |    3    |
|------------+---------|
```

If I use a simple JOIN like this:

```
SELECT ID, MODEL, USERNAME
FROM CARS
JOIN LIKES ON CAR_ID = ID
```

It will return this:

```
|  ID  |   MODEL   |  USERNAME  |
|   3  |  FERRARI  |   KEVIN    |
|   3  |  FERRARI  |    PAUL    |
```

That is incomplete

If I use something like this:

```
SELECT ID, MODEL, USERNAME
FROM CARS
LEFT JOIN LIKES ON CAR_ID = ID
```

I will have this:

```
|  ID  |   MODEL   |  USERNAME  |
|   1  |   FORD    |    NULL    |
|   2  |   OPEL    |    NULL    |
|   3  |  FERRARI  |   KEVIN    |
|   3  |  FERRARI  |    PAUL    |
|   4  |    GM     |    NULL    |
```

That is still incorrect, even if better.

The double record for the FERRARI will be removed adding a condition to the join:

```
SELECT ID, MODEL, USERNAME
FROM CARS
LEFT JOIN LIKES ON CAR_ID = ID AND USERNAME = "KEVIN"
```

This will return:

```
|  ID  |   MODEL   |  USERNAME  |
|   1  |   FORD    |    NULL    |
|   2  |   OPEL    |    NULL    |
|   3  |  FERRARI  |   KEVIN    |
|   4  |    GM     |    NULL    |
```

That is the correct list.

Once I've got this list I need to show it to the user, checking

```
if USERNAME is not NULL then DISABLE LIKE BUTTON
```

(PSEUDOCODE)

I hope this is useful to somebody

Comment: dude great explanation, i improved this a bit by using ORDER BY to get the ordering of the first table but other than that everything works perfectly! thanks

Comment: Hi again, i have something strange. when i am placing the statement in phpmyadmin i am getting the proper response from the db however when i am placing the same statement in php it seems that it takes everything till "LEFT JOIN". its like it acting as a delimiter 

SELECT * FROM cars_for_sell LEFT JOIN user_favorite ON cars_for_sell.id=user_favorite.favorites_id AND user_favorite.username = 'john' AND cars_for_sell.car_category=10 ORDER BY cars_for_sell.id 

the response should return in json encoding, are you familiar with that behavior maybe?

Comment: Great you solved, will you please share with other users how you did?

Comment: Well it was an issue within my php code the sql statement was good